# How to export to csv with concatenated columns

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I want to export mysql data to csv file with concat 4 columns,But it does not work can any one help me for this ASAP
I want to concat Add1,Add2,Add3,City,Pincode these columns And it will shows in single column in csv file

Thnx in advance

My PHP code as follows

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");



//Enter the headings of the excel columns
$contents="SR NO,DATE,AGENT NAME,PROCESS,DONAR NAME,ADDRESS,CONTACT NO,NEAREST STATION,SUBURBANS,PICKUP TIME,CONFIRMATION STATUS,PICKUP AMOUNT,FIELD EXECUTIVE\n";

//Mysql query to get records from datanbase
//You can customize the query to filter from particular date and month etc...Which will depends your database structure.
$Sr_no=$_GET['Sr_no'];
$dt=date('Y-m-d');

$user_query = mysql_query("SELECT Sr_no,Entry_Date,Agent_Name,Process_Name,Donar_Name,CONCAT( IFNULL( Add1,  '' ) , ' ', IFNULL( Add2,  '' ) , ' ', IFNULL( Add3,  '' ),' ',IFNULL( City,  '' ),'', IFNULL( Pincode,  '' ) ) AS Full_Address,Mobile_no,Nearest_station,Suburbans,Pickup_time,Confirmation_Status,Pickup_Amount,Field_Executive FROM leads where Entry_Date='$dt'");

//While loop to fetch the records
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{

$contents.=$row['Sr_no'].",";
$contents.=$row['Entry_Date'].",";
$contents.=$row['Agent_Name'].",";
$contents.=$row['Process_Name'].",";
$contents.=$row['Donar_Name'].",";
$contents.=addslashes($row['Full_Address']).",";
//$contents.=$row[{['Add1']}{$row['Add2']}{$row['Add3']}].",";
$contents.=$row['Mobile_no'].",";
$contents.=$row['Nearest_station'].",";
$contents.=$row['Suburbans'].",";
$contents.=$row['Pickup_time'].",";
$contents.=$row['Confirmation_Status'].",";
$contents.=$row['Pickup_Amount'].",";
$contents.=$row['Field_Executive']."\n";

}



// remove html and php tags etc.
$contents = strip_tags($contents); 

//header to make force download the file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Leads For".date('d-m-Y').".csv");
print $contents;



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$contents.=$row[{['Add1']}{$row['Add2']}{$row['Add3']}].",";
```

to this:

```
$contents.="{$row['Add1']}{$row['Add2']}{$row['Add3']},";
```

Comment: How do i change with select query                                $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT Sr_no,Entry_Date,Agent_Name,Process_Name,Donar_Name,Add1,Add2,Add3,Mobile_no,Nearest_station,Suburbans,Pickup_time,Confirmation_Status,Pickup_Amount,Field_Executive FROM leads where Entry_Date='$dt'");

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood you.. I thought you wanted to concatenate the PHP variables, not return a concatenated value from the SQL query. That being the case, @Orangepill has the correct answer.

Comment: Hello Nick,

As per you suggest i made the changes but it is not working , can you pls help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
$contents.=$row['Add1'].$row['Add2'].$row['Add3'].",";
```

Comment: Hi, Can i change with select query                            $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT Sr_no,Entry_Date,Agent_Name,Process_Name,Donar_Name,Add1,Add2,Add3,Mobile_no,Nearest_station,Suburbans,Pickup_time,Confirmation_Status,Pickup_Amount,Field_Executive FROM leads where Entry_Date='$dt'");

Comment: Yes. You can change. You have to remove this line $contents.=addslashes($row['Full_Address']).",";

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
SELECT Sr_no,Entry_Date,Agent_Name,Process_Name,Donar_Name,
       CONCAT_WS(" ", Add1,Add2,Add3,City,PinCode) AS Full_Address,
       Mobile_no,Nearest_station,Suburbans,Pickup_time,Confirmation_Status,
       Pickup_Amount,Field_Executive FROM leads where Entry_Date='$dt'");
```

Then it is a good idea to use fputcsv as opposed to building a string yourself for the output

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Leads For".date('d-m-Y').".csv");
$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
fputcsv($fp, array("SR NO","DATE","AGENT NAME","PROCESS","DONAR NAME","ADDRESS","CONTACT NO","NEAREST STATION","SUBURBANS","PICKUP TIME","CONFIRMATION STATUS","PICKUP AMOUNT","FIELD EXECUTIVE"));
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
   // strip tags out of the field
   $row = array_map("strip_tags", "row");
   fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Hello, 
As per your suggestion i made the changes but it not working.  Is it any other way to do this .